# Magento 2 : How to get order id in guest checkout before success page?

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento 2.1.3. I want to get order id in guest checkout before success page. I have search on google and found some  code like this.

```
$orderIncrementId = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId();
```

Using chcekout seesion \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session object, I have try to get order id but it does not work.
In magento 1.x , we can easily get order id from checkout session using same method. In magento 2.x we can not able to do this.

In magento 2.x How to get order id in guest checkout before success page ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->reserveOrderId();
$order = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getReservedOrderId();
```

Comment: Pretty weird how you create an accepted answer for yourself when the exact same answer has been given one year before. Could better accept that one.

Comment: In checkout session when i am refresh order id is automatically changes means sequentially if orderId is 9 and when i am refresh checkout page it will be 10, Please take a look for it

Answer (score 12):

try these lines of code :

```
$this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->reserveOrderId();
$reservedOrderId = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getReservedOrderId();
```

Comment: $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->reserveOrderId(); 
Using this line, magento set order increment id. after this statement , you can get order id  by following statement :
$order_id = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getReservedOrderId();

Comment: please  edit your answer to help someone.  THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Comment: Can idea how to do this via API ?